# How to grep using a variable in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

From what I've found on this website and other online sources it says to use double quotes around the variable.  But that's not working for me.

For example:

My variable is `$GTUNNELNATNETIP`

```
[johnwayne:630 ~] GTUNNELNATNETIP=`cat iptables.out |awk '{print $NF}'|cut -d "/" -f1`
[johnwayne:631 ~] echo $GTUNNELNATNETIP
10.19.192.0
[johnwayne:632 ~]
```

and the file I'm searching in is `iptables2.out`

searching without quotes finds the value but not without error

```
[johnwayne:632 ~] grep $GTUNNELNATNETIP iptables2.out
grep: : No such file or directory
iptables2.out:-A POSTROUTING -s 10.19.192.0/22 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 64.134.58.175
[johnwayne:633 ~]
```

It doesn't work with double or single quotes.  Or any other format I've tried

```
[johnwayne:633 ~] grep "$GTUNNELNATNETIP" iptables2.out
grep: Trailing backslash
[johnwayne:634 ~] grep '$GTUNNELNATNETIP' iptables2.out
[johnwayne:635 ~] grep `echo $GTUNNELNATNETIP` iptables2.out
grep: : No such file or directory
iptables2.out:-A POSTROUTING -s 10.19.192.0/22 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 64.134.58.175
[johnwayne:636 ~] /bin/grep $GTUNNELNATNETIP iptables2.out
/bin/grep: : No such file or directory
iptables2.out:-A POSTROUTING -s 10.19.192.0/22 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 64.134.58.175
[johnwayne:637 ~]
```

It works when I pass the actual value without an error

```
[johnwayne:637 ~] grep 10.19.192.0 iptables2.out
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.19.192.0/22 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 64.134.58.175
[johnwayne:638 ~]
```

So why does that grep error occur when the file and directory do exist?  And how can I pass the variable without error.  I'm trying to count how many lines the grep returns and get the exact `iptables` command without it showing the file name.

like this:

```
[johnwayne:637 ~] /bin/grep 10.19.192.0 iptables2.out
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.19.192.0/22 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 64.134.58.175
[johnwayne:638 ~]
```

as opposed to this:

```
[johnwayne:620 ~] grep $GTUNNELNATNETIP iptables2.out
grep: : No such file or directory
iptables2.out:-A POSTROUTING -s 10.19.192.0/22 -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 64.134.58.175
[johnwayne:621 ~]
```

Comment: Could you provide the output of ``echo "$GTUNNELNATNETIP"`` ?

Comment: Show output of `echo "$GTUNNELNATNETIP" | cat -vte`?

Answer (score 3):

You should quote it

```
grep "$GTUNNELNATNETIP" iptables2.out
```

[Read more about quoting variables in bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)
This must work.

I cannot reproduce your `trailing backslash` error, but most probably you have some garbage in `$GTUNNELNATNETIP` variable

Comment: But in the question it says that he tried it and got `grep: Trailing backslash` (No idea why this could happen).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `echo $GTUNNELNATNETIP` without quotes causes the shell to remove "insignificant" shell special characters. Use `echo "$GTUNNELNATNETIP"` and you will find that it does indeed have a trailing backslash, and possibly other problems.

(Better yet, learn to use `printf`, `set`, or `env` to examine your variables.)

The assignment [uses `cat` uselessly](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) and could use some additional refactoring anyway. Try this?

```
GTUNNELNATNETIP=$(awk '{split(/\//,g,$NF); print g[1] }' iptables.out)
```

... but this doesn't attempt yet to fix the problem, because we don't know exactly how the value is flawed. Maybe just add `gsub(/\\/,"",g[1]);` before printing?